# iPhone won't turn on

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4 with a broken power button. Today it suddenly went black even though there was more than enough battery left and won't respond when I hit the home button or try to charge it in an outlet or in the computer.

This has happened once before, but it was an easy fix when I could just hold the power and home button in for several seconds, but now I can't do that because the power button is jammed.

Does anyone know of another way to turn the iPhone on again without using the powerbutton or charging it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you belong to a very large, very angry community.

[That community > 800,000 has decided to sue Apple over this issue.](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2013/05/apple-sued-for-5-million-over-iphone-4s-faulty-power-button)

You can wait for the outcome of the lawsuit, or have it done for $150, or try some DIY for $5 for the part.

One other way is to try to clean the stuck power button.

Use a can of compressed air (for computers) found in computer stores and blast it. You can also try to flood it with some alcohol (ethanol or isopropanol) to try to wash out debris.

To be more effective, removing the back cover (two screws) could help.

If neither of these worked then you can consider replacing the power button.

There are plenty of [online instructions](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+iPhone+4+Power+&+Lock+Button/4332/1) on how to replace the power button.
I won't fool you, that procedure is not easy. It is time consuming and requires lots of patience and skills + tools... that is why the angry mob. :)